# Android: How to select all checkbox true when click on button using custome listview

Tags: android

> Blockquote  Hi, I am reading Contacts from the phone and displaying in custom listview with two textview and one checkbox. **I want to select checkbox as well as deselect  when click on option menu named "Mark all"**. How can i do? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get all item and set to true in a loop

```
final ListView list = getListView();
for ( int i=0; i< getListAdapter().getCount(); i++ ) {
        list.setItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

Edit:
in adapter class you can find CheckBox view and set it to true in a condition you want. and reload adapter.

Comment: Where i put this code. In main activity or in custom adapter class

Comment: Adapter class. this is where you control child inside listview items. good luck

Comment: pass a value to your adapter and make checked to all checkboxes and notify adapter.

Comment: HI Sir, I have create the class named Contact Detail and stores boolean value in it and Stores all object of Contact Detail class in arraylist. Now how can i select all checkbox in adapter class.What in oncheckedchanged method or other defined method i try notifydatachanged method or notify