# How to set Validation in Checkbox Android for all checkboxes check or not in Request validation method

Tags: android, validation

I am making basic application in Android, I want to check all my check-boxes and using `RequestValidation()` method. here my code.

```
public class InititalStepTwoFragment extends Fragment {

        InitialStepListener stepListener;


        public void setStepListener(InitialStepListener stepListener) {
            this.stepListener = stepListener;
        }

        public void requestValidation() {

        }

        public InititalStepTwoFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_initital_step_two, container, false);
            return v;
        }

    }
```

Comment: here is how you can mark all checkBox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479777/android-how-to-select-all-checkbox-true-when-click-on-button-using-custome-list/42479810#42479810

Comment: @EliasFazel please read my question about REQUEST VALIDATION METHOD.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code, here vg is the base layout

```
public static boolean validateAllCheckBoxt(ViewGroup vg){
    boolean validate = true;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++){
               View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
               if (child instanceof CheckBox){
                   if(!((CheckBox)child).isChecked()){
                       validate = false;
                       break;
                   }
               }else if (child instanceof ViewGroup){
                   validateAllCheckBoxt((ViewGroup)child);
               }
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle ex
    }
    return validate;
}
```